# Showing a toast over an interstitial ad

Tags: android, toast, interstitial

In my app sometimes when a interstitial ad displays it can happen that a toast gets to be shown, when that happens toast immediately disappears, so the user cannot read the toast message.

I'd like to know if threre's some way to show the toast on top of ad, so the user can continue on reading the message.

I think the interstitial ad works like some type of new activity so it's not possible, but I'd like to know for sure.

If not I guess I could change the toasts, with a text on SnackBar or something like this.