# Display a toast after clicking an item in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, toast

If I click on `RecyclerView` item I should get toast category id.
I've tried many times but I was not able to get a toast.

I'm using api. If I get this toast it will be very simple for me to see **id**.

```java
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I don't get id from these I'm new Android Developer

```java
adapterRecipes.setOnItemClickListener((v, obj, position) -> {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityRecipeDetail.class);
intent.putExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC, obj);
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
startActivity(intent);
adsManager.showInterstitialAd();
});
```

adapter

```
package com.app.yourrecipesapp.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.app.yourrecipesapp.R;
import com.app.yourrecipesapp.config.AppConfig;
import com.app.yourrecipesapp.databases.prefs.SharedPref;
import com.app.yourrecipesapp.models.Category;
import com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterCategory extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCategory.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> items;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    SharedPref sharedPref;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Category obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public AdapterCategory(Context context, List<Category> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.sharedPref = new SharedPref(context);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView category_name;
        public TextView recipe_count;
        public ImageView category_image;
        public MaterialRippleLayout lyt_parent;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            category_name = v.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            recipe_count = v.findViewById(R.id.video_count);
            category_image = v.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
            lyt_parent = v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_category, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Category c = items.get(position);

        holder.category_name.setText(c.category_name);

        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RECIPE_COUNT_ON_CATEGORY) {
            holder.recipe_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.recipe_count.setText(c.recipes_count + " " + context.getResources().getString(R.string.recipes_count_text));
        } else {
            holder.recipe_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Picasso.get()
                .load(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/upload/category/" + c.category_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                .into(holder.category_image);

        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, c, position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListData(List<Category> items){
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void resetListData() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

category.java

```
package com.app.yourrecipesapp.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Category implements Serializable {

    public int cid = -1;
    public String category_name;
    public String category_image;
    public String recipes_count;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? But you can put an onClickListener on your AdapterClass view holder

Comment: @LecheDeCrema check please i will update code adapter

Comment: I think that You are facing a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217951/showing-a-toast-over-an-interstitial-ad Seems like interstatial ads cancel toasts.

Comment: @sweak hi need click image show toast category  id how to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24885223/7639296) this is the best way to implement clicking on the item of RecyclerView**

Firstly create a file `values/ids.xml` and put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id" />
</resources>
```

then add the code below to your source

### for Java

Copy the following helper class to your project

```
public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                // ask the RecyclerView for the viewHolder of this view.
                // then use it to get the position for the adapter
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            // every time a new child view is attached add click listeners to it
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        // the ID must be declared in XML, used to avoid
        // replacing the ItemClickSupport without removing
        // the old one from the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        // if there's already an ItemClickSupport attached
        // to this RecyclerView do not replace it, use it
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

### Usage:

just call it from activity / fragment like the following

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView)
        .setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        // do it
   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

(it also supports long item click)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917564/7639296)

Comment: sorry i am new android devloper how to merge code

Comment: just follow the instruction in my answer, and copy the class `ItemClickSupport` to new class

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your adaptor

```
var onItemClick: ((YourDataClass) -> Unit)? = null
```

And then in your onBindViewHolder

```
val item: HouseDataClass = yourItems[position]
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClick?.invoke(item)
    }
```

And then in your activity/Fragment

```
myAdaptor.onItemClick = { it ->
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: this java coding

Comment: how should get toast category id

Comment: i need java coding

Comment: Paste this in android studio. Android studio will give you option to convert this to java and the id is passed in onItemClick you can access it from there